# Transforming particular epoch time

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hi i am trying to transform this epoch time to something readable in postrgesql

```
1541030400
```

Wanted to transform a value with his day year and month

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-datetime.html

Comment: `select to_timestamp(1541030400)`